# How can i override django contrib comments template?

Tags: python, django, templates, comments, overriding

The django contrib comments form i'm using:

```
{% get_comment_form for post as form %}
<form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {% if next %}
        <div><input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" /></div>
    {% endif %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% if field.is_hidden %}
            <div>{{ field }}</div>
        {% else %}
            {% if field.name == 'comment' %}
            {% if field.errors %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
            <p
                {% if field.errors %} class="error"{% endif %}
                {% ifequal field.name "honeypot" %} style="display:none;"{% endifequal %}>
                {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
            </p>
            {% endif %}             
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="post" class="submit-post" value="{% trans "Post" %}" />
    </p>
</form>
```

After submitting the form, it redirects to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/comments/posted/?c=..`

That means it calls the template `django/contrib/comments/templates/comments/posted.html`

The content of `django/contrib/comments/templates/comments/posted.html`:

```
{% extends "comments/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{% trans "Thanks for commenting" %}.{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>{% trans "Thank you for your comment" %}.</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

That doesn't extends my project's base.html.

I need to customize/override that template so that it extends my project's base.html. How can i do that?

If i can't do that, then if i upload my django web project on server, then how would i edit the content of `django/contrib/comments/templates/comments/posted.html` so that it looks like that:

```
{% extends "path/to/myproject/templates/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{% trans "Thanks for commenting" %}.{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>{% trans "Thank you for your comment" %}.</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

On local pc, for this time i changed/edited the content of `django/contrib/comments/templates/comments/posted.html` hard-coded to extends my project `base.html`.

Can anyone give some idea to solve this? I have searched a lot to solve this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just override it in your project's "templates" directory:

```
<project_root>/templates/comments/posted.html
```

It doesn't seem to be well documented in either the comments app or Django's general template documentation, but it works the same as [overriding admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) (which is documented).

Comment: It always annoys me when I try to explain this to people and can't find backing documentation :/ In fact, that's why I didn't answer!

Comment: However, I guess it bears mentioning that the bit in the admin documentation about custom templates per app/model doesn't apply here. That's a special case scenario for the admin.